# Не работает программа на С++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, i = 0, x;
    int a[i];
    cin >> n;
    while (n > 0) {
        i++;
        a[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
    }
    int l = i;
    x = a[4];
    for (i; i >= 1; i--) {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i; i >= 2; i--) {
        a[i] = a[i - 1];
    }
    a[1] = x;
    for (i; l >= 1; i--) {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Почему-то не хочет первый элемент вставать на место последнего.

Comment: начнем с того что у вас неопределенное поведение. i=0; int a[i]; итого ваш массив нулевой длины. дальше смотреть код не имеет смысла потому как может происходить все что угодно, когда возникнет повреждение стека

Comment: `for (i; l >= 1; i--) { .. }` - при `l >= 1` это бесконечный цикл, например.

Comment: Хорошо, как мне тогда сделать масив с длинной і?

Comment: @goodalien1125 использовать std::vector или new int[i].

Comment: @goodalien1125 "маССив", "длиНой". В том-то и дело, что вы создаёте массив с длиной `i`, А переменная `i` равна нулю - это написано буквально в предыдущей строке кода.

Comment: @Regent Упс, я не русский) Так вот, ну а как мне сделать массив, которые будет увеличиваться в соответствии с і?

Comment: @goodalien1125 alexout вам предложил пару вариантов. Ещё можно создать массив с фиксированной, заведомо больше нужной длиной. но это из серии "Вредные советы".